# Converting a recursive implementation to a loop based implementation

Tags: java, closures

I have two interfaces which is responsible for holding a closure

Here is the first one for holding the closure when it comes to a map operation.

```
package com.fs;

/**
 * This interface is responsible for holding the closures when it comes to map.
 * It uses two generic types. One for the argument and one for the return type.
 * @param <B> Generic type 
 * @param <A> Generic type
 */
public interface Func<B,A> {
    /**
     * Function prototype m takes an argument of type A and returns a type B.
     * A map operation can produce a different type.
     * @param x of type A
     * @return type B
     */
     B m(A x); 
}
```

And the second one for filtering operations

```
package com.fs;


/**
 * This interface is responsible for holding the closures when it comes to filter.
 * @param <A> Generic type 
 */
public interface Pred<A> {
    /**
     * Function prototype m takes an argument of type A and returns a boolean.
     * A filter operation checks every element if it fits a predicate.
     * @param x of type A
     * @return boolean
     */
    boolean m(A x);
}
```

I have a class named CList which is capable of working with closures.

```
package com.impl.list;

import com.fs.*;

public class CList<T> {
    T head;
    CList<T> tail;

    public CList(T x, CList<T> xs){
        head = x;
        tail = xs;
    }

    static <A,B> CList<B> map(Func<B,A> f, CList<A> xs){
        if(xs==null){
            return null;
        }
        return new CList<>(f.m(xs.head),map(f,xs.tail));
    }

    static <A,B> CList<B> maploop(Func<B,A> f, CList<A> xs){
        //?????
        return null;
    }

    static <A> CList<A> filter(Pred<A> f, CList<A> xs){
        if(xs == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(f.m(xs.head)){
            return new CList<>(xs.head, filter(f,xs.tail));
        }
        return filter(f,xs.tail);
    }

    static <A> int length(CList<A> xs){
        int ans =0;
        while(xs!= null){
            ++ans;
            xs=xs.tail;
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Here is my public interface implementing CList with closures.

```
package com.impl.list;

import com.fs.Func;
import com.fs.Pred;

public class CListClient {
    public static CList<Integer> doubleAll(CList<Integer> xs){
        Func<Integer, Integer> df = new Func<Integer, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer m(Integer x) {
                return x * 2;
            }
        };

        return CList.map(df, xs);
    }

    public static int countNs(CList<Integer> xs,final int n){
        Pred<Integer> pf = new Pred<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean m(Integer x) {
                return x==n;
            }
        };
        return CList.length(CList.filter(pf, xs));
    }

    public static CList<Integer> doubleAllloop(CList<Integer> xs){
        Func<Integer, Integer> df = new Func<Integer, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer m(Integer x) {
                return x * 2;
            }
        };

        return CList.maploop(df, xs);
    }
}
```

And a simple tester:

```
package basic;


import com.impl.list.CList;
import com.impl.list.CListClient;
import org.junit.Test;


public class ListTester {

    CList<Integer> intlist_1 = new CList<>(new Integer(1),null);
    CList<Integer> intlist_2 = new CList<>(new Integer(2),intlist_1);
    CList<Integer> intlist_3 = new CList<>(new Integer(3),intlist_2);
    CList<Integer> intlist_4 = new CList<>(new Integer(4),intlist_3);
    CList<Integer> intlist_5 = new CList<>(new Integer(4),intlist_4);
    CList<Integer> intlist = new CList<>(new Integer(5),intlist_5);

    @Test
    public void test_doubleAll(){
        CList<Integer> doubled = CListClient.doubleAll(intlist);
        CList<Integer> doubledloop = CListClient.doubleAllloop(intlist);

    }

    @Test
    public void test_CountNs(){
        int count3s = CListClient.countNs(intlist, 3);
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert the map function which is implemented in a recursive way to a while loop. I named it maploop. It hurts my brain for two days.Any hint will make me very happy.I am asking this question here since there is probability that someone may take Dan Grossman course and see the example and try to implement that function. I prefer a hint than an actual answer. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When converting a recursive function to an iterative function, you have to examine which non tail call state is required, if any. Then create a stack and push the states onto the stack, and code it like you would the recursive function otherwise. If you have multiple recursive calls in the function, you'll need your new state item to also contain a value indicating at which point in the function you are.

In this case, you only have one recursive call, and the only state is `xs`, so things are pretty simple and you don't need a custom state object.

Here's how I'd do things (not tested).

```
static <A,B> CList<B> maploop(Func<B,A> f, CList<A> xs){
    Stack<CList<A>> stack = new Stack<>();

    while(xs != null){
        stack.push(xs);
        xs = xs.tail;
    }

    CList<a> result = xs;

    while(!stack.empty()){
        xs = stack.pop();
        result = new CList<>(f.m(xs.head), result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: result = new CList<>(f.m(xs.head),result); this is the line that I can not see for two days :(((((((

Comment: it may cause stack to overflow:)

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach to transform a recursive program to an iterative one, is via a tail-recursive variant. As a very simple example, consider the following recursive factorial function, to compute `N!`:

```
int factorial(int x) {
    if (x == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return x * factorial(x-1);
}
```

Call `factorial(N);`.

Making this tail-recursive involves adding an accumulation variable:

```
int tailRecursiveFactorial(int x, int y) {
    if (x == 0)
        return y;
    else
        return tailRecursiveFactorial(x-1, x*y);
}
```

Call `tailRecursiveFactorial(N, 1);`

This one is straightforwardly transformed to an iterative program:

```
int x = N;
int y = 1;
while (x != 0) {
    y = x*y;
    x = x-1;
}
```

Of course, your problem is a good deal harder, but the general approach should still work.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all problems can be transformed into tail recursion (except for the trivial transformation of passing an explicit stack). For more complicated recursive functions, you'll have to create your own stack.